Using an ESR Meter to measure in-circuit capacitors' equivalent series resistances with 100kHz test frequency (via MESR-100 ESR Meter)?
So, I have an image of an ESR Meter from YouTube. It is the relatively popular [Brand Unknown] MESR-100 entry-level standalone ESR meter. Please see image below.
So, below the LCD on the faceplate, it reads "100KHz In Circuit Tester"[sic]. To me, this indicates that it may be used on a capacitor in circuit while it uses its 100kHz test frequency and still yield reasonable results. I've watched a few YouTube videos where people say that, generally speaking, measuring in circuit doesn't yield good results because of peri-circuit component interactions and associated parasitics.
Would using a meter like this be okay for in-circuit testing? Are there any resources one may provide to guide a hobbyist such as myself?
Thanks.



100KHz would be 100 kelvin-hertz so I'd have my doubts about their attention to detail. Capitals matter!

You are not wrong, thank you. I will change that. Any answer regarding the content?

@Velvet Thank you for your edits.

Answer:
Yes, technically, you may take a measurement. But, that measurement will not be close to the out-of-circuit measurement. That is because that single measurement will vary from the true value depending on the circuit configuration.
A zeroing strategy may be employed in theory, but that's beyond the question. Further potential strategies are discussed below.
A Practical method:
The simplest and easy answer for the most accurate measurement is to measure the component out of circuit.
The problem:
But, the above practical method that takes time, work, and some material (solder, flux, wick, etc.)--and if you have many components to do or have limited equipment (say no reflow unit), your time-costs and error-costs (losing components, breaking components, disorganizing removed components) jumps up drastically. So, we can consider some theory as to how one may try to attempt to reduce the variance from the true value. Also, there is risk of heat stress, physical stress, and loss or damage of the component (with our without expertise). Also, because of limitation and the type of board your working on, if you are working with lead-free solder for example, you may use 60/40 or a different ratio to remove the component and thus contaminate your board--this may matter depending on your constraints and preferences. Thus, there is a good reason to consider alternatives to removing the component.
So, as suggested in the question's details section, the issue with testing capacitors in-circuit is that the para-circuit configuration may have components that react and affect the measurement (like resistors, other capacitors (say in a series of parallel bypass caps) ontop of confounding unexpected parasitic effects (say from the conductors/traces, or other bad components). Ceteris paribus, each unique configuration that one tests a capacitor around may impact the accuracy of the reading when compared to that of an out-of-circuit equivalent capacitor.
Depending on the components and configuration, you may be able to find a possible solution.
The theory behind a potential solution
With that said, after doing some reading and digging, it does appear that my suggestion was correct--that frequency of the signal does indeed impact the behavior of a capacitor, which can impact the usefulness of the in-circuit measurement's in an attempt to approach the true value (all-else-equal) of the equivalent out-of-circuit capacitor.
Let's figure this out together this year of 2024.
This relationship is summarized by the following proportionality:

I.e., The total capacitive reactance (due to the capacitor under test (CDUT)) is inversely proportional to the frequency of the AC current applied.
Thus, as frequency increases, capacitive reactance of CDUT decreases. And,by corollary, as the frequency decreases, the capacitive reactance of CDUT increases. Thus, then, the goal is to approach a pure capacitive reactance, which requires a lowering frequency. However, this alone does not fully stop the influence of other nearby circuit components, as the same relationship applies to all of those surrounding components as well as you lower the frequency. So, lowering frequency is the first step. Let's consider the next steps to understand my problem.
So, how does one practically try to get around the issue of external components influencing your measurement? This is my best guess as to how it would theoretically work:
Briefly, I would argue to use a lower test voltage (if possible).
The explanation as to why follows: With a higher electrical potential difference, the current that reaches the other components has more energy to "power" the other components, which then can be impeded and reacted to by said para-circuit components. So, in keeping the voltage low, the goal is to not provide too much energy for the electrons to do any materially significant work inside the para-circuit components that surround our capacitor of interest (CDUT). Now, using the proportionalities associated with Ohm's Law, consider that:

So,

With that in mind, as we reduce voltage, we reduce the resistance that is contributed to the ESR of CDUT. So, we get a cleaner ESR for CDUT.
Then, we switch our focus to current. I don't think there's a manual option for even the higher-end, portable ESR or LCR meters to manually select a current as the AC signal generator of the meter is expected to have its voltage altered by an in-series variable resistor. The hope is the testing device produces more current as voltage drops (considering Ohm's Law) via the variable resistor of the measurement device, where that current is enough to fill the other pathways with charged electrons in the surrounding circuit, but with low enough voltage that those electrons don't have enough energy to drive the surrounding, para-circuit components to impact the current flow paths such that they complete a circuit that reaches the negative test lead (which acts as a ground here) (i.e., the resistors and capacitors surrounding CDUT work as approaching-0-resistance resistors, which current approaches being undefined). (From my understanding, you also don't want a grounded board with a ground lower than your test lead of your measurement device that is acting as ground, as then the board's lower ground affects the reading.) So, this idea can be summarized using Ohm's law again, arranged for the current-resistance proportionality:

And,

Essentially, due to the inverse relationship, the higher the current, the lower the resistance.
That's the explanation behind the solution. Now, for the solution.
Solution
Thus, taken together, you want:

LOWER TEST VOLTAGE (meaning low resistance, meaning less impact to your ESR reading--your device may or may not have a manually variable test voltage feature)
HIGHER TEST CURRENT (meaning low resistance, also meaning less impact of other components to your ESR reading--don't think you can generally change this in one's portable measurement devices)
Then, DECREASED the FREQUENCY (f) to increase the capacitive reactance

So, with all of this said, it seems that it's not impossible to get a decent read from your/my ESR meter and/or LCR meter.
It always helps with comparable (a second working circuit board that is the same layout), then you can measure things relatively.
If we're looking for absolute values, I do think one would have to measure at different test frequencies, then use the appropriate circuit analysis math. I also think you might be able to do multiple measurements at different parts so as to isolate equivalent circuits, then subtract those equations out of a supra-equation to yield CDUT.
Sounds like lots of work, but pencil and paper is more forgiving than a broken component or lost component--especially if you realize you don't have the exact one if you do get the measurement. Don't want to have a tiny SMD sitting around a giant work desk for days ideally right? :/
Caveat
BUT.... that's still not as good as just removing the component and testing it out of circuit. Understandably, that takes a lot of work and time as discussed--so, there is good reason as to why one would want to measure things in-circuit if you can.

Unless there are components in your circuit that change their impedance with voltage, such as diodes, the measurement voltage will affect all oomponents equally. Thus changing the measurement voltage level will not be effective. Changing the current measurement level will also not work for the same reasons.

Components just can't be measured in-circuit due to other components  Period.

"Let's figure this out together this year of 2024." Sorry, this isn't a discussion forum. It's a question and answer site. "... where that current is enough to fill the other pathways with charged electrons in the surrounding circuit ..." This is techno-babble, I'm afraid.

@Transistor  Hi Transistor, with all due respect, this is the second off-colored criticism you've left here. That is not techno-bable--its a description of basic classical physics theory. May you please state your credentials from what you are basing your opinion? Are you an out-of-college technician or au university educated engineer? Though I am not an expert electrical engineer, I have a lot of background from various STEM fields that collapses on basic physics principles regarding theory. I am discussing things from a simplified classical model of the electron.

@Justme Yes, you've mentioned and I understand the logic. However, to be fair, one may, technically, measure the in-circuit component but the actual measurement will be further from the true value, depending on the surrounding circuit configuration.  And, by measuring, I did imply just 1 measurement, so your answer is valid.
That said, what if we take multiple measurements and do circuit analysis, then is there  a hypothetical possiblity? I am very motivated to find a thorough answer as to why or why not.
Thank you, good sir! :)

@Justme I editted my answer, please take a look and respond as you see fit accordingly. :)

You can measure a cap in-circuit but then you are measuring the whole circuit, not just the capacitor.
So no, you can't measure capacitors in-circuit if you only want to measure the capacitor.
Imagine you want to measure a capacitor, but it is paralleled with another capacitor. Then you are measuring both capacitors at the same time, in addition to other circuit.
Despite the marketing claim and branding, be careful when measuring things in-circuit.

Appreciate this answer @Justme.
To follow up, I had a possible theory that at higher frequencies and lower voltages, you can sort of isolate the "damage" done by the para-circuit reactances and such.
Though what you do say makes sense. Are you familiar with the impedance computations for an LCR/ESR meter and the effects of frequency on said circuit? And, if so, can you consider a further answer?
Thank you, sir! :)

@PrashanthC 100 kHz sine wave has a wavelength of 2 kilometers on PCB. Even if the test signal is square wave and has so fast slew rate that it has frequencies up to 100 MHz, the 100 MHz still has a wavelength of 2 meters. The caps are likely closer together than that, but also the PCB trace parasitics start to affect it. And there are other components on the same wires, such as resistors, ICs, diodes, transistors, so you are not measuring the capacitor, but all that connects to the capacitor.

Interesting, thank you. I just presented an answer. Perhaps, that answer suggests the opposite answer you provide because I went a different route! (lol!)  Anyways, interesting points thank you!

No meter can evaluate capacitors in-circuit for all possible circuit configurations. A meter might work OK for typical circuits and typical values of the capacitance.
If the meter gives the expected capacitor value and low leakage the capacitor is probably OK. If the results are not OK the capacitor might be bad. Do you feel lucky?

Appreciate this answer @Fred,
To follow up, I had a possible theory that at higher frequencies and lower voltages, you can sort of isolate the "damage" done by the para-circuit reactances and such.
Though what you do say makes sense. Are you familiar with the impedance computations for an LCR/ESR meter and the effects of frequency on said circuit? And, if so, can you consider a further answer?
Thank you, sir! :)

Impedance or admittance measurements (at moderate frequencies) are performed by sourcing voltage and measuring current (or source current and measure voltage), forming the ratio, and resolving in-phase and quadrature components. The existence of any alternate current paths and/ or series parasitics will influence the measurement. The only question is the degree. And the degree depends on details- the specific frequency, real and imaginary parts, parasitics, and alternate current paths. No general rule about frequency, voltage, or whatever will guarantee accurate results. It is necessary to actually think about the circuit configuration. And those of us who perform accurate and defensible measurements do our best to understand the influence of parasitic components and leakage paths.
